# A feature to choose project type is not showing in Visual studio when creating new projects, how can I out it back?

Tags: visual-studio

[My visual studio when I would create new projects is this a new feature or I messed up the settings?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBnzB.png)

[The first image is supposed what my VS should look like when opening it or creating new projects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8iy6.png)

Answer (score 0):

i think you have messed up setting, try to run visual studio installer -> modify and see what workloads you have there.